# Why is my result significant when there is no difference between means?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, friedman-test

I have run a Friedman's test in R and it has given me the following result:

```
> pwc <- psheetv2 %>%
+   wilcox_test(score ~ time, paired = TRUE, p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")
> pwc
# A tibble: 3 × 9
  .y.   group1    group2       n1    n2 statistic        p p.adj p.adj.signif
* <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <int> <int>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1 score bvigilant pvigilant    67    64        28 0.000855 0.003 **          
2 score bvigilant rvigilant    67    51        43 0.012    0.037 *           
3 score pvigilant rvigilant    64    51       177 0.105    0.315 ns
```

But despite there being significant differences between the groups, all the group medians are 0. How do I work out the direction of effect if all the means are the same? Have I done this wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Nina. You seem to conflate "median" and "mean," but the two can be very different.  Which do you intend to ask about in your title and in your text?  Are you perhaps wondering how two group means can differ while their medians are equal?

Comment: @whuber, thank you for helping out! I am looking into medians because my data don't fit any assumptions for parametric tests and are not distributed normally. I think I'm confused about what exactly the significant difference in the Friedman's test denotes. I assumed it was that there was a significant difference between means, but I'm starting to think I'm wrong about that...